# LAST_TIME_CONTACTED returns 0

Tags: android

I can get contact id and name from my contact list. But LAST_TIME_CONTACTED returns 0. How can I get LAST_TIME_CONTACTED correctly ?

My code:

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
if (cur.getCount() > 0)
{
    while (cur.moveToNext())
    {
        String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
        String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
        String last = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LAST_TIME_CONTACTED));
    }
}
```

Comment: Please note that the constant LAST_TIME_CONTACTED has been deprecated in October 2018, along with TIMES_CONTACTED. See the [guide](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.ContactOptionsColumns#LAST_TIME_CONTACTED) and [reference](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider#ObsoleteData)

Answer (score 1):

[By the looks of things](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8784&q=LAST_TIME_CONTACTED&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars) this isn't properly implemented by all device manufacturers. As such it seems like an unreliable field to use unfortunately. Almost certainly the case if you're using a Samsung Galaxy device...

As a side note, I think it's stored as an integer so you might be better using `getInt()` but I doubt very much that that's the problem.

Comment: I have [Current Called ID](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.webascender.callerid) in my phone. It listed last time contacted info for all my contacts. How it achieve this?

Comment: Probably a custom SQLite database.

Answer (score 1):

Like Ed Hinchliffe said, it seems to be an unreliable field. However, you might be able to store such a value yourself if that is acceptable for your use case.

If you use a `BroadcastReceiver` and a `PhoneStateListener` you might be able to pull it off.

You would simply need to use `String.valueOf(currentDate.getTime());` and store the value somewhere.

Comment: I have [Current Called ID](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.webascender.callerid) in my phone. It listed last time contacted info for all my contacts. How it achieve this?